# Sencha cmd "app watch" fails

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.3.1
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160

After I generated sencha application using the command:

```
sencha generate app -name Stam -path ../StamApp
```

I tried run sencha app watch using:

```
sencha app watch
```

And the error I got is:

```
C:\sencha\StamApp\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:242: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\sencha\StamApp\.sencha\app\watch-impl.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\sencha\StamApp\.sencha\app\watch-impl.xml:40: Unknown attribute [refname]
```

Line 40 in **watch-impl.xml**:

```
    <x-run-compass-watch directory="${app.sass.dir}" refName="compass-watch"/>
```

Note that I installed sass and compass, and it still doesn't work.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Is it a touch app? Which Cmd version? Do you run `sencha app watch` from the app directory (../StampApp)?

Comment: Sencha Touch 2.3.1 , Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug, quoting an ExtJS Team Leader:

"Thanks all - that is the work around for this issue. We have it fixed for 5.0.1 and that is all it needed (removing "refName" from x-run-compass-watch call)"

Answer (score 4):

For people like me:

look at rootdir/.sencha/app/watch-impl.xml

here find line with and replace :

```
<x-run-compass-watch directory="${app.sass.dir}" refName="compass-watch"/>
```

with

```
<x-run-compass-watch directory="${app.sass.dir}" /> <!--refName="compass-watch"-->
```

Start sencha app watch again and it runs.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested it and I get the same error. It seems to be a bug, most likely in Sencha Cmd 5. Report it please on [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?92-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Bugs).